# Many to many relationship for same type entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many, bidirectional-relation

I have an entity as below. I am curious if it is possible to create a relationship as I will be describing with the example:

- I am creating 2 **Person** entities **Michael** and **Julia**.
- I am adding Julia to Michael's friends set.
- After that I am retrieving Michael as a JSON response and Julia is available in the response. But when I am retrieving Julia, her friends set is empty. I want to create the bidirectional friendship relation by saving just one side of the friendship. I would like to get Michael on Julia's friends set without doing any other operations. I think that it must be managed by Hibernate. Is it possible and how should I do it?

  ```
  @ToString(exclude = "friends") // EDIT: these 2 exclusion necessary
  @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "friends")
  public class Person{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name",unique = true)
  private String name;

  @JsonIgnoreProperties("friends") // EDIT: will prevent the infinite recursion
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "FRIENDSHIP",
         joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", 
  referencedColumnName = "id"),
         inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id", 
  referencedColumnName = "id"))
  private Set<Person> friends;
  ```

Here is my service layer code for creating a friendship:

```
    @Override
    public Person addFriend(String personName, String friendName) 
        throws FriendshipExistsException, PersonNotFoundException {
    Person person = retrieveWithName(personName);
    Person friend = retrieveWithName(friendName);
    if(!person.getFriends().contains(friend)){
        person.getFriends().add(friend);
        return repository.save(person);
    }
    else{
        throw new FriendshipExistsException(personName, friendName);
    }
}
```

> Related Question:
>   [N+1 query on bidirectional many to many for same entity type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562273/n1-query-on-bidirectional-many-to-many-for-same-entity-type)
>
> **Updated the source code and this version is working properly.**

Comment: You need to setup bidirectional relationship manually. Like `friend.addFriend(person) and person.addFriend(friend)`. If you want to handle such kind of relations, consider a graph database instead. I prefer to create a helper method inside my entity like `makeFriendship(Person person)` and setup the relations there to make the code more readable.

Comment: @BogdanOros I will be updating as this way but I am not sure that I should make it manually by adding to each other's friends list.

Comment: [Official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html) shows that it is how it works. It is done to support relations in database, because in a relation database you need to have two rows to specify this relation.

Comment: @BogdanOros I am aware of it and exactly asking if this is possible. I want to insert two rows in friendship table with just one save operation.

Comment: You will call the `save` operation ones, because you have configured cascades and it will automatically persist the child set with updated friendship relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Creating a graph to help hibernate to create a query with outer join.
@NamedEntityGraph(name="graph.Person.friends",
    attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "friends"))
class Person {}

interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    // using the named graph, it will fetch all friends in same query
    @Override
    @EntityGraph(value="graph.Person.friends")
    Person findOne(Long id);
}

@Override
public Person addFriend(String personName, String friendName) 
    throws FriendshipExistsException, PersonNotFoundException {
    Person person = retrieveWithName(personName);
    Person friend = retrieveWithName(friendName);
    if(!person.getFriends().contains(friend)){
        person.getFriends().add(friend);
        friend.getFriends().add(person); // need to setup the relation
        return repository.save(person); // only one save method is used, it saves friends with cascade
    } else {
        throw new FriendshipExistsException(personName, friendName);
    }
```

}

If you check your hibernate logs, you will see: 
*Hibernate: insert into person (name, id) values (?, ?)* 
*Hibernate: insert into person (name, id) values (?, ?)* 
Hibernate: insert into friendship (person_id, friend_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into friendship (person_id, friend_id) values (?, ?)

Comment: It is exactly giving the stackoverflow error on the line:

        `friend.getFriends().add(person);`

Comment: Tried same example , no stackoverflow error, could you paste stackstrace?

Comment: I just solved the stackoverflow error. Lombok's toString(), equals() and hashCode() methods were causing it. I excluded the friends element than it is solved. Now I have a problem while getting a person. For example when I get Julia, Michael is on the friend list and it is trying to get Michael's friend list and it is bringing Julia an it goes on as an infinite loop. It is N+1 query problem and I am trying to solve it.

Comment: Yes, Lombok cannot resolve backward references, that's why I moved to Kotlin with dataclasses etc.

Comment: Do you have any solution advice for the problem I mentioned up there?

Comment: Trying to configure `NamedEntityGraph` to setup correct fetching

Comment: I tried this solution but it is still giving this error.


Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion

Comment: check [Tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) how to handle recursion problems with json mappers

Comment: I had tried it before but it is not about Jackson. I want to get just friends of the root person. Hibernate is bringing it with N+1 query. I found that [Tutorial](https://martinsdeveloperworld.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/using-namedentitygraph-to-load-jpa-entities-more-selectively-in-n1-scenarios/).

Comment: I asked a related question about the infinite recursion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562273/n1-query-on-bidirectional-many-to-many-for-same-entity-type